Chrome extension | Getting non-logged in user's browser profile name
Is it possible to retrieve the local name of a browser profile that isn't synced by logging into a Google account?
To clarify, the Chrome's chrome.identity API provides access to the email and id of a logged-in user. However, I'm specifically interested in obtaining the user-defined name of a browser profile.
Has anyone reverse-engineered this or found a workaround?
